# GKE MultiClusterIngress with HTTP/3 support

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcp-load-balancer

I'm using GKE's `MultiClusterIngress` to set up a load balancer that routes traffic to the closest GKE cluster. The load balancer set up by `MultiClusterIngress` advertises HTTP/3 (QUIC) support in the `alt-svc` header. However when using `curl` with `--http3`, I am unable to connect:

```
* Connect socket 5 over QUIC to [redacted]:443
* connect to [redacted] port 443 failed: Failure when receiving data from the peer
* Failed to connect to [redacted] port 443 after 127 ms: Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

If I query the created load balancer using `gcloud`, I see that it has `quicOverride` set to `NONE`, which according to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#configuring-http3) means that it should support QUIC.

How do I get QUIC working?

Answer (score 0):

I was hitting the load balancer using its IP address instead of using a valid DNS name. Setting up DNS and using that works as expected.

---

If somebody is familiar with how QUIC works, I'd love to understand why setting the `Host` header is not sufficient to set up a connection.